# Is its against Facebook's Policies to open a share dialog while performing a separate action?

Tags: facebook, usability

The place I work keeps having us open share dialogs when users perform other actions. For instance, they press a button to enter the contest, but the text says "Share and Enter" and spawns a share dialog. I am concerned that this is against facebook's Terms of Service but couldn't find anything beyond broad guidelines, like "don't mislead users."

I am opposed to it because it is a really bad user experience, but in addition I'm worried if we violate ToS we could have all of our apps shut down which would harm the business considerably. Usability issues aside, is this sort of behavior allowed?

Comment: Why would you have a button called Share and Enter?

Comment: Because users want to enter contests for a chance to win stuff but generally don't want to share. Sharing increases performance indicators though so the social team makes us do slightly shady things like this in an attempt to increase them.

Comment: Sounds like you are doing it specifically to mislead the user

Comment: _“but couldn't find anything beyond broad guidelines, like "don't mislead users."”_ – what more do you need? If your site is tricking users into believing that they would need to share or that it would increase their chances of winning - then you are misleading them already.